# How to add a total row for exports from advanced order export for woocommerce plugin?

Tags: excel, wordpress, woocommerce, export

for a woocommerce shop I am using Single Products with Addons. These are quantity fields that are impacting the price at the end. Such as when you order a Pizza and can add multiple toppings in any quantity.

I need to be able to export a cumulative report that also shows the total amount of each addon. Since my addons are custom meta fields, I am using for the reports the "advanced order export for woocommerce" plugin from AlgolPlus.

With that plugin, I am able to export an excel file that adds for each addon a new column and shows per order the amount of each addon that was ordered. What I would need in addition now, is to display a total row at the end that shows the total amount of ordered addons.

Obviously I know that I can simply add myself a new row with the sum formula but this is for a client and ideally, I want that the report can do this automatically.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me,
But WooCommerce has a great API at https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction. That you might want to check and that might help you

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the developer, he write the basis of the code and I adjusted it to add last row to each exported XSL report and make that last row in bold font and yellow background color.

Here it is:

```
add_action( 'woe_xls_print_footer', function ($objXls,$formatter) {
$row = $formatter->last_row;
for($i = 0; $i < PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString( $formatter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn() ); $i++ ){
    $letter = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i);
    $formatter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue( $letter.($row+1), "=SUM(".$letter."2:".$letter.$row.")" );
}
$formatter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A".($row+1).":".$formatter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn().($row+1))->getFont()->setBold(true);
$formatter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A".($row+1).":".$formatter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn().($row+1))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF00');
$formatter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue( "A". ($row+1), "Total" );} ,10, 2);
```